# Programming: Classes VS Functions

Tags: function, class

Talking in general, (not referring to a particular programming language) is there one thing in the world that can be accomplished with classes only that functions cannot?

If the response is "no" What is the point in using classes instead functions in programming?

It seems to me that using classes code is more complex... but might be that I'm talking as newbie/profane...

Comment: @RyanVincent
**"The function has the data it manipulates always passed to it"**
Might be I'm misinterpreting the sense of the sentence you wrote but if I write into a function `var a='something'` I am "storing a state" into that function, without passing it to the fn itself, like a class. IMHO it is similar to write into a class the statement `this.a='something'`.

But maybe I still don't get the difference cause I'm just starting to approach class programming

Comment: you mean some way similar to nested functions where nested fn can access the parent function namespace? Or more similar to a global var?

Comment: ...then can we say that classes act more similarly to global variables?

Answer (score 0):

class is a data type. User defined data type in particular.

Function is a body of imperative statements.  so both are totally different things

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing a class can do that functions could not. In fact, the first C++ compiler simply translated C++ into C for compilation by a C compiler. However, there is also nothing a function can do that could not be accomplished by simply copying the body of the function to each location where it is used.

Both classes and functions provide different layers of abstraction. *Using* an abstraction is more complex, in a sense, than using what it abstracts, but the benefits of a good abstraction outweigh the cost of learning the abstraction. Functions allows code re-use; classes allow function re-use (by way of inheritance). Both provide different types of organization to make code easier to understand.